# Spinner options (an IcsSpinner from ABS) inside DialogFragment are displayed truncated

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-dialogfragment

I have the following problem displaying a `Spinner` inside a `DialogFragment`.

The `Spinner` is displayed cut and it's only displayed OK when the keyboard appears.

The `Spinner` is actually a custom class with the following code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner;

public class CustomIcsSpinner extends IcsSpinner {

  public CustomIcsSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.actionDropDownStyle);

  }

  public CustomIcsSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Spinner is displayed cut]
[image: Spinner is displayed OK]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner` source code.
Find `DropdownPopup popup = new DropdownPopup(context, attrs, defStyle);`
Replace with `DropdownPopup popup = new DropdownPopup(context.getApplicationContext(), attrs, defStyle);`

Works for me;

:)