# IcsSpinner (ActionBarSherlock) Inside DialogFragment is displaying truncated

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm referring to this question [Spinner options (an IcsSpinner from ABS) inside DialogFragment are displayed truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850337/spinner-options-an-icsspinner-from-abs-inside-dialogfragment-are-displayed-tru)

The next problem we face with this kind of solution is the spinner uses gingerbread touch feedback with ugly orange

How do we set the color of touch feedback in the spinner? Or at least, how to use default holo color instead?

I'm using custom adapter for spinner,

```
    public class CategoriesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategorieItem> {

    private static final String tag = "CategoriesAdapter";
    private ArrayList<CategorieItem> list;
    private Context c;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CategoriesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<CategorieItem> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);

        c = context;
        this.list = list;
        Clog.d(tag, "Constructor " + list.toString());
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            Clog.d(tag, "convertView is null");
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hiscat_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView catText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.his_category);
        Clog.d(tag, "Cat Text : " + list.get(position).getName());
        catText.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        catText.setTextColor(list.get(position).getColor());
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            Clog.d(tag, "convertView is null");
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hiscat_dropdown, parent, false);
        }
        TextView catText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.his_category);
        Clog.d(tag, "Cat Text : " + list.get(position).getName());
        catText.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        catText.setTextColor(list.get(position).getColor());
        return v;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you instantiated the spinner?

Comment: I use default implementation with custom list item. . @Rperryng will show you later

Comment: @Rperryng Just edited question, you can check the custom adapter I use,